# Not writing to my file in between two comments

Tags: python

I have a file that I am opening and trying to write to. I am trying to write data in between two comments in my file. However, when I run my program the file is erased and nothing is written. I am also not receiving any errors. I think it is because I need to read and then write, but I am unsure how to proceed.

```
with open(dipolepath+dipole+extension, 'w') as output_data:
# Skips text before the beginning of the interesting block:
    for line in output_data:
        if line.strip() == '//Antenna Structure':  # Or whatever test is needed
            break
            # Writes text until the end of the block:
        output_data.write(points3)
    for line in output_data:  # This keeps writing the file
        if line.strip() == '//Output Field Info':
            break
```

Comment: `break` exits the loop, not the if statement

Comment: You are opening the file in `write` mode and reading a from it. Try using `with open(dipolepath+dipole+extension, 'a') as output_data:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you you open a file in `w` mode, its content is cleared.

You need to open in `r+` mode to start from the beginning of the file and not clear it

And if you're trying to put content between the comments, check your logic. If you see a comment, that's when you start writing, not when to break

For example

```
start = False 

for line in output_data:
    output_data.write(line)  # If you want to preserve the content
    if line.strip() == '//Antenna Structure':  # Or whatever test is needed
        start = True
    if start:
        # Writes text until the end of the block:
        output_data.write(points3)
    if start and line.strip() == '//Output Field Info':
        break
```

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong, but it is writing to the end of the file with your edits. I have also tried a+, but it still isn't writing to the spot I want.

Comment: `r+` mode opens file at the beginning for editing. `a+` mode opens it at the end

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file in "w" mode deletes the contents of the file before you write anything to it. You may want to use "r+" mode, which allows reading and writing. Just change

```
open(dipolepath+dipole+extension, 'w')
```

to

```
open(dipolepath+dipole+extension, 'r+')
```

Comment: @cricket_007 fixed